Can Rstudio addins be available globally across renv activated projects
I want RStudio addins that I have installed to be available in any renv activated RStudio project I am
working on (I am not talking about package development projects here). Specifically, I want the styler package addins available, but this should be generalisable to any addin.
At the moment I do it by installing styler in each renv activated project, so not a big problem. But is there another solution (e.g. an option for development packages to be available globally )?
